# How to detect the print preview window of Excel 2003, with vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vsto

I need to be able to test if the current view is print preview in Excel 2003.

Is there something in the excel object model to simply access this property? (Like the application.printpreview in the Word object model...).

Any advice would be more than welcome,

Thanks

Julien

PS: Long story short, I'm developing a vsto addin with keyboard short-cuts to my custom functions, and I need to disable this shortcuts when print preview is on.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to determine if it is in `xlPageBreakPreview`

```
If Windows(1).View = xlPageBreakPreview Then
    ''# do your thing
End If
```

Note that `Windows(1)` always means "the active view".

**EDIT:** Re-read the question and saw you meant the actual print preview window. That is a dialog of `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrintPreview)`. It's only method is `.Show`. But it wouldn't really matter as code doesn't run when that dialog is open. It will only return two values - `True` and `False`. So `True` means *something was printed* and `False` means *the dialog was closed without printing*. You can return the value by doing something like this:

```
dlgPrinted = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrintPreview).Show
If dlgPrinted Then
    Debug.Print "The worksheet was printed"
Else
    Debug.Print "The user closed print preview without printing."
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
But It won't work since you can also view page breaks directly on your worksheet (I tested it anyway)...

Comment: @Julien V.: Sorry, I had misread the question. Please see updates above.

Comment: Thanks again for this quick answer, but I'm not sure that it's what I'm looking for.
As I understand it, your code will launch print preview, and tell us what the user did with it.
What I need is to be able, at any given time, to know if the user is actually seeing the print preview window.

PS: I'm working with vb.net and VSTO, so code is running when print preview is on...